# how to set vertical gridlines matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a time series plot showing each month and a value.

I added gridlines `plt.grid(True,which='major')`, and it shows for every month. My time series is 10yrs, and I only want to see 1 grid each year.

My major tick labels are:

```
ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
        11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,
        22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.,  32.,
        33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,
        44.,  45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.,  50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,
        55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,  59.,  60.,  61.,  62.,  63.,  64.,  65.,
        66.,  67.,  68.,  69.,  70.,  71.,  72.,  73.,  74.,  75.,  76.,
        77.,  78.,  79.,  80.,  81.,  82.,  83.,  84.,  85.,  86.,  87.,
        88.,  89.,  90.,  91.,  92.,  93.,  94.,  95.,  96.,  97.,  98.,
        99., 100., 101., 102., 103., 104., 105., 106., 107., 108., 109.,
       110., 111., 112.])
```

I tried to change my major tick labels with:

```
labels = ['']*len(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs())
idx=list(range(len(labels))[0::11])
for i in idx:
    labels[i]=ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()[i]
labels[len(labels)-1]=ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()[len(labels)-1]
from numpy import array 
labels=array(labels)
ax.set_xticks(labels)
```

labels are:

```
array(['0.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '11.0', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '22.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '33.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '44.0', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '55.0', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '66.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '77.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '88.0', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '99.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '110.0', '', '112.0'], dtype='<U32')
```

Unforunately, when I plot, all of the majorticklocs are unchanged, and I still see every month on the grid line.

my plot is made:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
plt.plot(SoldHx['month'],SoldHx['Price'])
fig.suptitle('Median Price by Month')

labels = ['']*len(SoldHx.index)
idx=list(range(len(labels))[0::12])
for i in idx:
    labels[i]=SoldHx['month'][i]
labels[len(labels)-1]=SoldHx['month'][len(labels)-1]

plt.xticks(SoldHx.month,labels,rotation=90)
plt.grid(True,which='major')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: "and I only want to see 1 grid each month."... There IS only one grid (vertical line) per month. Your question and the figure you posted seems contradictory at the moment. I clearly see 11 ticks between two consecutive years. Perhaps you want to explain what the real problem is

Comment: sorry, it is a typo, I wanted only 1 grid per year

Answer (score 0):

You only have set the major ticks, minor ticks are missing. I had once a similiar problem, I only wanted yearly major lines and quarterly minor lines, including tick labels. My solution looked about the following way (pd from pands...):

```
    years = list(range(2000, 2018))
    year_tick_pos = [pd.to_datetime(str(year) + "-01-01") for year in years]

    quarters = list()
    quarter_tick_pos = list()
    for year in years:
        for q in range(1, 5):
            new_quarter = pd.to_datetime(str(year) + "-" + str(q * 3 - 2).zfill(2) + "-01")
            if new_quarter <= limits[1]:
                quarter_tick_pos.append(new_quarter)
                quarters.append("Q" + str(q))

    ax.set_xlim(left=quarter_tick_pos[0] - pd.Timedelta('45 days'),
                right=quarter_tick_pos[-1] + pd.Timedelta('45 days'))

    ax.set_xticks(year_tick_pos)
    labels_major = ax.set_xticklabels(years)
    ax.set_xticks(quarter_tick_pos, minor=True)
    ax.set_xticklabels(quarters, minor=True, fontsize=8)
```

This snippet creted quarterly lines and anual lines in different style, maybe this can help you.